# How to increase or decrease all fields value by percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var Per=$(".per").val();
    $(".anuzau").each(function(){
      var Val=$(this).val();
      if($this.hasClass("zau"))
       $(this).val((((Val/100)*Per)+parseInt(Val)).toFixed(2));
      else if($this.hasClass("anu"))
       $(this).val((parseInt(Val)-((Val/100)*Per)).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

```css
.anuzau{width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="anu">-</button> <input class="per" type="text" size="6" value="0">%
<button class="zau">+</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" size="6" class="anuzau" name="name" value="38.5"><br>
<input type="text" size="6" class="anuzau" name="name" value="75"><br>
<input type="text" size="6" class="anuzau" name="name" value="100">
```

I wish to increments/decrements all values by classname (anu zau), can anyone share me the jquery method? I have tried many tutorials.
I am new here, if anything wrong, please correct me.

```html
<button class="anu">-</button> <input type="text" size="6" value="">%
<button class="zau">+</button>
<br><br>

<td><input type="text" size="6" class="anu zau" name="name" id="id" value="50"></td><br>
<td><input type="text" size="6" class="anu zau" name="name" id="id" value="200"></td><br>
<td><input type="text" size="6" class="anu zau" name="name" id="id" value="530"></td>
```

Comment: do u need change in percentage of basic data like "50" on each click or relative data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. Not clear what precision you are looking for (adjust decimal_points accordingly)

```js
var decimal_points = 2

$('button').click(function(){
  var pVal = $('#percent').val(),
  percent = pVal && !isNaN(pVal) ? +pVal/100 : 0;
  //make it negative if anu button clicked
  if($(this).hasClass('anu')){
     percent = 0-percent;
  }
  $('input.anu').val(function(_, val){
     // make sure input has numeric value
     if(!val || isNaN(val) ){
       return val;
     }else{
       return (+val + (val * percent)).toFixed(decimal_points);
     }
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="anu">-</button> <input id="percent" type="number" size="6" value="">%
<button class="zau">+</button>
<br><br>

<td><input type="text" size="6" class="anu zau" name="name" id="id" value="50"></td><br>
<td><input type="text" size="6" class="anu zau" name="name" id="id" value="200"></td><br>
<td><input type="text" size="6" class="anu zau" name="name" id="id" value="530"></td>
```

Comment: As i can see this code is working for me with 2 decimal points with 1%, why this answer is -vote? I am using that so, Is there anything wrong or any security issue with @charlietfl script?

Comment: Nothing wrong. Someone was probably being malicious

Comment: Ok, Your code is working perfect. Can you check one matter? When you enter the value of less than 0.50 and 1% with not increasing the value. Like enter 0.49 and 1%. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on decimal point precision desired. 1% of .5 won't be reflected in 2 decimal places

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    var Per=$(".per").val();
    $(".anuzau").each(function(){
      var Val=$(this).val();
      if($this.hasClass("zau"))
       $(this).val((((Val/100)*Per)+parseInt(Val)));
      else if($this.hasClass("anu"))
       $(this).val((parseInt(Val)-((Val/100)*Per)));
    });
});
```

```css
.anuzau{width:200px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="anu">-</button> <input class="per" type="text" size="6" value="0">%
<button class="zau">+</button>
<br><br>
<input type="text" size="6" class="anuzau" name="name" value="50"><br>
<input type="text" size="6" class="anuzau" name="name" value="200"><br>
<input type="text" size="6" class="anuzau" name="name" value="530">
```

Comment: no need for 2 identical loops when only one variable is different

Comment: @Farhad Bagherlo, Hi, really great. can you review again with press 1 in percentage value. That's not reflect value of 50. The problem only if  percentage value is 1.

Comment: Yes, thats perfect but can you check please when 2nd click, the values are working except 50 value.

Comment: Because it is used in `toFixed(2)` and continues to two decimals. You can increase the `toFixed(10)` value to 10 or more and see the result

Comment: i removed `toFixed(2)`. please try agin

Comment: @Farhad Bagherlo, I just updated your code snippet. Maybe something wrong :P can you use an calculator to check with different percentage output values?  Two decimals is okay.

Comment: I tested several times. I did not see any problems. Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, If the value is 0.10 and percentage is 1%, then the value comes wrong or not working while continue clicking. Then the click hit on the + icon 1st time is ok, 2nd time not ok. Hopefully understood.

Comment: In the your example , the number becomes too small and leaves the variable range. As you know, when a decimal fragmentation action is performed. The exact answer is not reached . https://ibb.co/mykz0b

Comment: It is because `parseInt` removes the decimals and errors start compounding on multiple clicks